# Sklearn Lasso regularization not dropping out random variables?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

I've been using SelectFromModel from sklearn to reduce features using LASSO regularization and I'm finding that even when I set max_features to quite low (low enough to negatively impact performance) the random variables are often kept.

I generated an example with fake data to illustrate, but I'm seeing similar with actual real data and I am trying to understand why.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from numpy import random

    
data = datasets.make_classification(n_features = 20, n_informative = 20, n_redundant = 0,n_samples= 1000, random_state = 3)
X = pd.DataFrame(data[0] )
y = data[1]

X['rand_feat1'] = random.randint(100, size=(X.shape[0]))
X['rand_feat2'] = random.randint(100, size=(X.shape[0]))/100

embeded_lr_selector = SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(penalty="l1", 
                                                         solver='liblinear',random_state = 3),max_features=10)
embeded_lr_selector.fit(X, y)
embeded_lr_support = embeded_lr_selector.get_support()
embeded_lr_feature = X.loc[:,embeded_lr_support].columns.tolist()
print(str(len(embeded_lr_feature)), 'selected features')
print('Features kept', embeded_lr_feature)
```

Even though I've set 20 variables to be informative, and added 2 completely random ones, in many cases this will keep rand_feat2 when selecting the top 10 or even top 5. On a side note I get different results even with random state set....not sure why? But the point is fairly often a random variable will be included as a top 5 feature. I am seeing similar with real world data, where I have to get rid of a huge chunk of the variables to get rid of the random feature....makes me seriously doubt how reliable it is? How do I explain this?

EDIT:

Adding a screenshot along with sklearn/pandas versions printed... I'm not always getting the random features included, but if I run it a few times it will be there. On my real world dataset at least one is almost always included even after removing about half the variables.

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to recreate your issue.  I ran your code with 50 different random states and rand_feat1/rand_feat2 were never included in get_support().  Can you post your output showing their inclusion?  What sklearn/pandas are you running?

Comment: Added screen to the post.  I just ran it 100 times and the rand2 feature was in there just under half the time (45%). Rand feat 1 is never in there however